# 2D json array erroneously gets converted to a string

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, json

I have an outer array with 2 elements inside.  Each of the 2 elements is an array.  So it's a 2-dimensional array.

Here is how the array is created:

```
 $outerArray = array();
 $nestedArray =  array("first", "second", "third", "fourth");
 $outerArray[] = $nestedArray;
 $nestedArray_2 =  array("first", "second", "third", "fourth");
 $outerArray[] = $nestedArray_2;
```

I then store this array as follows:

```
 $jsonArray = json_encode($outerArray);

 // USE 'echo' TO PUT THIS array INTO A HIDDEN input FIELD ON THE PAGE
 echo "document.getElementById('jsonArray').value = $jsonArray;";  


 // LETS ECHO THE NESTED ARRAY TO VERIFY IT WAS CONSTRUCTED CORRECTLY
 echo $jsonArray;
```

Here is the HTML hidden element 'jsonArray' in my file:

```
  <input type="hidden" id="jsonArray" />
```

That echo I did just above here shows me the array looks like this:

```
  [["first","second","third","fourth"],["first","second","third","fourth"]]
```

All this is good.  Right now it's clear that the hidden input field has a valid 2D json array stored in it.

I then do the following with the array -- I store it in the session, redirect to another file, which extracts then echoes the 2D array:

```
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
   { 
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      {
          // SEE NOTE #1 BELOW ABOUT WHAT THIS SHOWS IN THE ALERT() BOX
          alert("The xmlhttp.responseText is: " + xmlhttp.responseText);


          window.location = "theViewer.php";
      }
   }

   var arg = "theStored2dimensionArrayAsJson=" 
                   + document.getElementById('jsonArray').value;
   xmlhttp.open("POST", "handler.php", true);
   xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
   xmlhttp.send(arg);
```

So what this does, it sends the json-encoded 2-dimensional array to handler.php.  And all handler.php does is save the json-encoded 2-dimension array in the $_SESSION:

```
   // in handler.php
   $_SESSION['jsonEncoded2D_Array'] = $_POST['theStored2dimensionArrayAsJson'];

   // echo out the array so it appears in the xmlhttp.responseText
   echo $_POST['theStored2dimensionArrayAsJson'];


   // NOTE #1 -- THIS IS WHAT IS DISPLAYED IN THE xmlhttp.responseText
   handler.php, the jsonEncoded2D_Array is:          
        first,second,third,fourth,first,second,third,fourth
```

After displaying the xmlhttp.responseText in an alert() box, I redirect to theViewer.php.
I retrieve the 2D array from the SESSION and echo it out:

```
   // INSIDE theViewer.php
   $jsonified_2D_Array = $_SESSION['jsonEncoded2D_Array'];
```

But when I echo out the 'array' I just retrieved from the SESSION, it's a string now, not an array:

```
   // THE echo SHOWS THE 2D ARRAY HAS BEEN COVERTED TO A TEXT STRING
   // AND IS NO LONGER AN ARRAY
   echo "Okay, here is the 2D array:<br />" . $jsonified_2D_Array;
```

The output of the echo just above is this:

```
    Okay, here is the 2D array:
    first,second,third,fourth,first,second,third,fourth
```

I don't get this.  If you look at the code above, I echo this array after putting it into a hidden input field and it looks **correct**, like a 2D array.  And that is **after** I converted it to JSON.

Then I take that JSON-ified 2D array out of that hidden field, pass it via Ajax to handler.php in order to save in the SESSION, AND then take it back out of the SESSION in theViewer.php -- and **it is no longer a 2d array** -- it is now just a text string.

I need to keep this 2D array **as a 2D array** and not a string.

Is this possible?  I need the 2D array (not a stringified array) in **theViewer.php.**

I tried JSON.parse() and eval() on the stringified array in theViewer.php and it stopped code execution, it did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$asd = '[["first","second","third","fourth"],["first","second","third","fourth"]]';
var_dump(json_decode($asd));
```

outputs

```
array(2) {
  [0]=> array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "first"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "second"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "third"
        [3]=>
        string(6) "fourth"
  }
  [1]=> array(4) {
        [0]=>
        string(5) "first"
        [1]=>
        string(6) "second"
        [2]=>
        string(5) "third"
        [3]=>
        string(6) "fourth"
  }
}
```

so json_decode() is the answer

EDIT: so the answer was wrapping it inside quotes like this

```
echo "document.getElementById('jsonArray').value = \'$jsonArray\';";
```

so ajax will treat it as string and will not remove brackets.

Comment: Dang that looked promising.  No change though.  There is something happening to the array when I Ajax-it over to handler.php for storage in a SESSION variable, but I just don't see it.  It's screwing with the array enough so that json_decode() cannot recover it.

Comment: try echoing it the when you get it from ajax and post how it looks please :) like echo $_POST['jsonarray']; and post how it looks

Comment: I've already done that above -- look at the block above that says "in handler.php" and you'll see what that echo-ing shows.  It already shows it's no longer an array but I wasn't sure if that was conclusive.  If the array-to-string happens in the Ajax process, I sure don't see how or why.

Comment: var arg = "theStored2dimensionArrayAsJson=" 
                   + document.getElementById('jsonArray').value; how does the array look in there is it still intact or is it just plain text?

Comment: also why does it need to go through ajax and not just straight to session?

Comment: trouble is, I just echo'd the 2D array in a php file (handler.php) and it looked fine, then I instantly echo'd it into that 'jsonArray' hidden field -- theres NOTHING that would change it to a string.  When I call alert(document.getElementById('jsonArray').value) it looks like first,second,third,fourth

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49630/discussion-between-bountyh-and-cfhcoder)

Comment: because I need it in that hidden field with 100% certainty. But the Session source of that array is used infrequently.  I need it both on the client (html/javascript) presence  *and* the server (SESSION) presence.